# Explanation for proper Implementation of downloading HTML Source Code from a given URL in a String Variable

Tags: java, android, html, download

So I am using AsyncTask in Android to receive an URL in Intent and intend to download the source code of the HTML Page of the URL and search for specific terms in the String, but whenever I try to download it, the following text is shown in the Label I intend to see my Source Code:

[image: error image]

Source Code I have been using is listed below:

```java
@Override
        protected String  doInBackground(String... urlS) {
            String html = "";
            BufferedReader br;
            String line;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlS[0]);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    html+=line;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                mue.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //Final Touch Ups
            }
            toContinue=true;
            return html;
        }
```

So anyone got any idea why this is happening, and what does "$DownloadFile@" means ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Source Code I have been using is listed below" -- there is no "label" (`TextView`?) in this code, so we cannot help you with the code that sets text in it. "what does "$DownloadFile@" means ?" -- that is the output of `toString()` called on an instance of a `DownloadFile` class. If this is from a screenshot of the contents of a `TextView`, you called `setText()` on the `TextView` and passed in a `DownloadFile` object.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You Very much. The Problem seems to be solved, and I really think I need to work more on my Programming. Thank You Again for this Help. Can you please add this comment in the Answer Section so that I can mark it as Correct Answer ? And I am really sorry again for my poor choice of words while describing my Problem especially for TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you have a `TextView`, and you are calling `setText()` on it. The object that you are passing to `setText()` would appear to be an instance of a `DownloadFile` class. That is not your HTML. Make sure that you are passing your desired text to `setText()` on your `TextView`.